# How to iterate over multiple result sets of a custom query?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo, cakephp-3.0

I have a stored procedure in my mysql database which returns multiple query result sets.
I want to access these results in my cakephp(V3.4) project using following code statements.

```
  $db = ConnectionManager::get('default');                  
        $stmt = $db->execute("call mydatasp($paramlist)");
        $result = array();                     
        try{
                do
                {
                    $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll('assoc');
                    $result[]=$rowset;
                } while($stmt->nextRowset());
            }
            catch(Exception $e){}
```

After execution of this code block, I m getting error as

***[Cake\Error\FatalErrorException] Call to undefined method Cake\Database\Log\LoggingStatement::nextRowset()***

How can I access these multiple query resultsets?

Comment: Try with [getInnerStatement()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Database.Statement.StatementDecorator.html#_getInnerStatement). Something like `while($stmt->getInnerStatement()->nextRowset())` might work.

Comment: using this i get error as  *Call to undefined method Cake\Database\Statement\MysqlStatement::nextRowset() *

Comment: Update to my previous comment: - I have modified my code as below                                          
            do
                    {
                        $rowset[] = $stmt->getInnerStatement()->fetchAll('assoc');
                        $result=$rowset;
                    } while($stmt instanceof StatementDecorator);                                                 Now its giving me result for only first query. second query result is missing. I don't understand what I m doing wrong here?

Comment: NO one to help on this topic?